# Symfony - modify data from databases

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I would like use somethings - if i have encode, then i add in News.class.php **public function save** and use strtoupper. This working good.
How can i make somethings if i get data from database?

my DB:

```
id | title  | body
1  | title1 | body1
2  | title1 | body2
```

etc.

if i use **$news->getTitle()** then i have: **title1**
i must make:

**strtoupper($news->getTitle())** - it is good, but i dont will every time add my function decode. 
I would like use $news->getTitle() and at once this is strtoupper. Where i can this make? Which file? I dont will edit model generated auto with Symfony. I would like make this in **NewsTable.class.php**, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `News.class.php` (not the table) file and add this:

```
public function getTitle()
{
  return urldecode($this->title);
}
```